# Why does this HTML/CSS/jQuery code only work in CodePen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

This code works fine in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdash86/3ZQkM/), but not locally in Chrome or Firefox. Am I doing something wrong in linking the CSS or JavaScript? In the Firefox console, I get an error that `$` is undefined. Am I linking jQuery improperly?

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Digital Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">


    </div>

<script src="etch-a-sketch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

main.css:

```
//Etch-A-Sketch - CSS

.square {
  float: left;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

etch-a-sketch:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var wrapper = $('#wrapper');

  for (var i = 0;i < 16; i++) {
    var div = $('<div class="square"></div>');
    wrapper.append(div);
  }

});
```

Comment: My error was in my CSS. I commented JavaScript style and the caused the browser to not recognize the styling to `.square`. Although, it did still apply styling to `#wrapper`. I updated my CSS code to show where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the jQuery library *before* you include your custom script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="etch-a-sketch.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you're trying to use jQuery functionality before you have library available.

Comment: No luck still... Although the `$` error is now gone. How should I go debugging this? The CSS and custom script are both linked according to the console.

Comment: @JohnD. So you're 100% sure both your scripts and your CSS has loaded? Any errors at all? Try refreshing the cache (F5).

Comment: And I figured it out. I used JavaScript style commenting in my CSS... Thanks a lot for sticking around :)

Comment: It works just fine for me when I have all of the CSS/JS/HTML all in one file.  Are you sure your JS and CSS are linked properly?  Is the paths *actually* pointing to the files?

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aG3S/)

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lArxs/)

The error lies in Jquery ! you have to use `.html()` to inform the jquery to extract the `#wrapper` from the HTML document.

By the way, this also works

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 0;i < 16; i++) {
    $('#wrapper').append('<div class="square"></div>');
  }
});
```